# How to use Parse.com booleans in subclasses

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have subclassed PFUser and added a property isManager

```
class User : PFUser, PFSubclassing {
 @NSManaged var isManager: Bool
 override class func load() {
  self.registerSubclass()
 }   
}
```

I tried

```
user.isManager = false
```

but get the run time error

```
[Foo.User setIsManager:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x145bf550
```

I also tried using NSNumber because of core data

```
user.isManager = NSNumber(bool: false)
```

but get the compile time error

```
NSNumber is not convertible to bool
```

Comment: you ever figure this out?

Comment: @mikekavouras I've added what I ended up using. Hope it helps

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've actually found it to be much simpler to implement "get" and "set".

```
class User: PFUser, PFSubclassing {
    var isManager: Bool {
        get { return self["isManager"] as! Bool }
        set { self["isManager"] = newValue }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: In addition to the "unrecognized selector" error I was also getting the error "Type info TB,N,D not yet supported". Worth mentioning to help anyone else find this page.

Answer (score 1):

Set the bool using NSNumber

```
currentUser!.isManager = NSNumber(bool: true)
```

Then use the following for if statements

```
if currentUser!.isManager.isEqualToNumber(NSNumber(bool: true))
```

And then in your class:

```
class User : PFUser, PFSubclassing {
 @NSManaged var isManager: NSNumber
 override class func load() {
  self.registerSubclass()
 }  
}
```